# Compare each row string from columns and add condition to evaluate and print the result in new column

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe as below

```
string1  string2   var1  var2
  T        T        1     1    
  T        F        0     1
  F        F        0     0
```

I want to iterate through each row which has n number of rows and add conditions like below

```
 Iterate n number of rows
    if(string1 == T & sting2 == F){
      if(va1 > 1 & var2 > 1){
        # do some operation and append to new column
        # For example
        new column <- var1 + var2
       }
     elif(var1 == 0 & var2 > 1){
          # Do some adds / subs with var1 & var2 and append to new column
          }
     elif{var1 > 1 & var2 ==0){
          # Do some adds / subs with var1 & var2 and append to new column
     } 
    }
   elif(string1 == F & sting2 == T){
    # again repeat set of if-else opration on var1 and var2 as mentioned in 
       above if else condition
   }
   elif(nth condition)
```

How do i achieve in R

Comment: What would be the expected output for given example?

Comment: @RonakShah outout would be based on the var1 and var2, if string1 and string2 are T, then need to evaluate the var1 and var2, if both are greater than 0, output would be addition of var1 and var2

Comment: @user2277472 Please edit your question to add the expected output.

Comment: @vincrichaud. Updated the question with multiple if else condition to validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string1 <-c(T,T,F)
string2 <-c(T,F,F)
var1 <- c(1,0,0)
var2 <- c(1,1,0)
df <- data.frame(string1,string2,var1,var2)
df
  string1 string2 var1 var2
1    TRUE    TRUE    1    1
2    TRUE   FALSE    0    1
3   FALSE   FALSE    0    0
df$new_column <- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(x[1] == T & x[2] == T & x[3] > 0 & x[4] > 0, x[1]+x[2], NA))
df
  string1 string2 var1 var2 new_column
1    TRUE    TRUE    1    1          2
2    TRUE   FALSE    0    1         NA
3   FALSE   FALSE    0    0         NA
```

Replace `NA` with `0`, if you want to have `0` in the final result.

Comment: Thanks! But i have n number of conditions to validate, your solution holds good to validate one condition and update the nth column

Comment: You can modify `ifelse()` and put as many conds as you want (before the first comma). If you want some nested stuff I'll recommend to put another ifelse as first condition of previous one, or just run above command several times with different conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description in comments I think you need is

```
df$new_col <- with(df, ifelse(string1 & string2 & var1 > 0 & var2 > 0, var1 + var2, 0))

df
#  string1 string2 var1 var2 new_col
#1    TRUE    TRUE    1    1       2
#2    TRUE   FALSE    0    1       0
#3   FALSE   FALSE    0    0       0
```

This adds up `var1` and `var2` if `string1` and `string2` is `TRUE` and both `var1` and `var2` are greater than 0 or else it keeps `new_col` as 0.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, but i have many "if" conditions to add once string1 and string2 are True.

Comment: If the 1st condition is not met, it will proceed to next condition, if that condition is true, new_col have to updated

Comment: @user2277472 Can you edit and clarify those conditions in your post?